# How to delete old logs when starting a Python script which use TimedRotatingFileHandler?

Tags: python, logging

Here is the code snippet

```
# file handler
hdlr = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(log_dir, log_fn), "midnight", backupCount=3)
```

But this is a python script that usually took 5 minutes, but never ran at 00:00

So it seems all old logs before 3 days ago didn't be deleted.

How do I delete old logs when starting this script?

Comment: TimedRotatingFileHandler doesn't seem like the appropriate handler here. Why not just create a new log each time it's run? Also, log mgmt should probably be delegated to the next level up from the code generating the logs, since it won't have enough context to know what should be deleted.

Comment: @Bey You're right, RotatingFileHandler seem like the better handler here. Thanks!